# I can't get this to run on start Up

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this python code, which when I run it, it works and brings me to YouTube. I'm trying to get it so every time I boot up the raspberry pi it will run my python code and take me straight to YouTube. The rc.local file runs but it says

> could not locate runnable browser

Here is my python program

```
import webbrowser, os, sys

url = "http://www.youtube.com"
chrome_path = '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser'

def main():
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

main()
```

Here is my rc.local file

```
python /home/pi/browserOpen/OpenBrowser.py &
exit 0
```

Comment: UPDATE: I just need to figure out how to open a cmd terminal on start up for a raspberry pi. I need it to open up like as if you were to click on the icon just need it to do it on its own on start up

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `main()` function like this:

```
def main():
    webbrowser.register('chrome', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path), 1)
    webbrowser.get('chrome')
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2)
```

and set `chrome_path` to `"/usr/bin/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"`

UPDATE:

Try creating .sh file in the same directory as your .py file, put `/yourpath/bin/yourscript.sh &` in `rc.local` and this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
python scriptname.py
```

in yourscript.sh file.

Original answer from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46125)

Comment: That code does work, but it still won't run when the raspberry pi boots up